# Make movable windows in Flash

Tags: flash, web, window, mouse, drag

WARNING: I'm new to Flash, but I figured that Flash would be the best for the result I'm going for.  I am making an Adobe Flash website and part of the website includes a box that is draggable and movable around the screen.  So, to keep it simple, how can I make it movable?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it's very easy, a quick search on google  [highlight this snippet](http://snipplr.com/view/3507/), just use startDrag() stopDrag() and flash does all the work :-)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks so much!  Not only do I now have an answer to my question, I now have this really cool site with code snippets.  So, double-thank you!